# View IBM Cognos active report on smartphone

Tags: smartphone, cognos-bi

This [link](http://www.ironsidegroup.com/2010/12/14/ibm-cognos-10-%E2%80%93-active-reports-is-it-a-solution-for-your-organization/) says that active reports developed by IBM Cognos 10 can not be rendered on mobile [Refer last line under "Are there any Red Flags with IBM Cognos 10 Active Reports"]. Is it true?

My second question is- can I view active report through normal browser in smartphone without installing IBM Cognos Mobile?

Development environment: 
IBM Cognos BI 10.1.1 Report Studio;
IOS/Android smartphone

Comment: 1. That was then, whatever the link said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your version of Cognos.  As of 10.1 initial release, there was no support for Active Reports on mobile devices, so that link is correct for that version.

As of 10.1 Refresh Release 1 (AKA 10.1.1) it is supported on the iPad using the Cognos Mobile application.  You can see the Active Reports section was added to the Supported Environments page for 10.1.1: http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27022474